# How to determine the value at a position of a sorted array after K rotations?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have an array of Size 4 and there are 5 elements

```
1)  0,1,2,3
2)  4,0,1,2 after 1st rotation
3)  3,4,0,1 after 2nd rotation
4)  2,3,4,0 after 3rd rotation 
5)  1,2,3,4 after 4th rotation
6)  0,1,2,3 after 5th rotation
```

as we can see the number repeats itself after 5 iterations.
Is there an efficient way to search for kth element of the array ? after say N rotations??

Comment: Where is the 5th element stored? What would the difference be if the size was 5 and all elements were in the array?

Comment: not 5 elements sorry 4 elements my bad!

Comment: No,its an array of size 4 only

Comment: @DebarshiDutta `0,1,2,3,4` are 5 elements as a see in the above example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume array indices are zero-based.

To compute the index of the Kth value of an M-element array after N rotations you should use the following expression

```
(K + N) mod M
```

So given an array `arr`, you should get the value like this (using C-like syntax):

```
arr[(K + N) % M];
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would be to put the combinations in to some sort of an array, and directly index the number. It would probably be worth it to make sure the numbers are valid beforehand as well. I believe this will do (Assuming first row is 0, first column is 0, adjust if you want to change the start point by addition)

```
elements=[0,1,2,3,4]
out=elements((K-N)%5
```

Quick test:

```
N=1, K=3, out=2 correct
N=5, K=1, out=1 correct
```

Comment: Thanks I now see how it works , just keeping one extra value will do the trick..  thanks man!